# Authorizing Node.js (with socket.io) with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, sockets, socket.io

so we are currently using a Rails application as our primary backend but we are also using a node.js server with socket.io to allow for some realtime updating data on each page. Setting up the connections and socket.io rooms is fine right now, the issue is I need to validate that a user has permission to access the information in the room they are trying to join. What I need to do is validate that the user making the javascript socket.io request is logged in on that same session to the rails server (I.E. If someone tries to access data restricted to user X on the node server, they must be logged in as user X on the rails server). I'm using sorcery on the rails server for my account authorization.

My initial idea for this was to store two cookies in the user session when they log into rails: a session_token and their email. Say user X logged in once again, his email is X@mail.com. X's account credentials (user and password) are validated on rails and the two cookies are stored in his session. Then the rails server would store X@mail.com's session_token in the SQL database. Then X navigates to a page with a socket.io connection. Then the node server would read these cookies, find the user with that email, and validate that their session token cookie is the same as the entry in the database. If it is, they effectively are now logged in on the node server and I can give them access to the same information they would have on the rails server. Is this an effective solution, or are there potential security holes here?

I'm very familiar with Rails, but new to node.js/socket.io, so I'd ask that you are fairly descriptive when describing node stuff.

Comment: If the only thing the node socket.io server is using to auth the user is an email address in a cookie, anyone who knows a logged-in users email addr could spoof into being authenticated in the socket.io server. I'd suggest using a token that is recognized cross-platform, such as [JWT](http://jwt.io/).

Comment: @KevinB How could they spoof in if they did not know the cookie for that specific user? Each user has their own token. If the spoofer did know the cookie for that specific user, they would already have access to a lot of other vital data, like their Rails_Session cookie. wouldn't they? (I'm not trying to argue that what I have said is the best method, but I'm not sure if I understand your argument.)

Comment: The way i understood your explanation was that the node.js side wasn't using the token cookie, it was just using the email cookie to look up to see if the session was still active. **I see, i misinterpreted your explanation.**

Comment: @KevinB It is using the email cookie to find the user in the database. It then checks if the session_token cookie is the same as the entry in the database row associated with that user.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on the surface if you're using both cookies to confirm.